# Why is a Pytest Parametrize not recognized when the method is called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have this Python code:

```
import pytest
class Apple:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("kind", ['fruit', 'veg', 'nuts'])
    def mix_kind_and_colour(self, kind):
        print(kind)
        return self
    def runner():
        return Apple.mix_kind_and_colour()    
    if __name__== "__main__":
        runner()
```

But I get this error:

> TypeError: mix_kind_and_colour() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'kind'

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

> Please have look at pytest's [docu](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html), it's quite fine.

You don't need classes, until you want to group tests.

But you need to follow some [naming conventions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#test-discovery).

A simple working example of a test_sample.py for running `pytest` command from your terminal would be:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("kind", ['fruit', 'veg', 'nuts'])
def test_mix_kind_and_colour(kind):
    print(kind)
```

If you want to use a class try to run `pytest` for:

```
import pytest

class TestApple:

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("kind", ['fruit', 'veg', 'nuts'])
    def test_mix_kind_and_colour(self, kind):
        print(kind)
```

But you additional need some [assertions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html) for testing something?!?

```
# content of test_assert1.py
def f():
    return 3

def test_function():
    assert f() == 4
```